# "Clipboard empty or not valid" error when copy/pasting images across Word documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

Confused beginner here.
I am trying to copy all images from one Word document to a different document.
This sub only works for the first image (or last one, looping from the end).

After that, a few more inlineShapes get deleted, but not pasted, until I get error 4605 "This method or property is not available because the Clipboard is empty or not valid".

I googled error 4605 but did not get any wiser.

How can the clipboard be empty or why is it not valid?

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes()
    Dim docOpen As Document
    Set docOpen = ActiveDocument
    Dim docNew As Document
    Set docNew = Documents.Add
    Dim i As Long
    
    docNew.SaveAs2 FileName:="Images.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    
        For i = docOpen.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            docOpen.InlineShapes(i).Range.InsertAfter "image00" & CStr(i)
            docOpen.InlineShapes(i).Range.Select
            Selection.Copy
            docNew.Content.Paste
            docOpen.InlineShapes(i).Delete
        Next i
    docNew.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Word but it seems you may need to define each word document individually for the code to be able to parse between the two documents. I think when you're opening the new word doc, it's then becoming your active document. If your code is saved in the document you're manipulating, try changing `Set docOpen = ActiveDocument` to `Set docOpen = Thisdocument`

Comment: @Brett, thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggested, but the result was the same: one single image gets copied to the new document, a few more get deleted from the old document, then the error appears.

Comment: I'm having trouble with Word, so I can't test it. This line `docOpen.InlineShapes(i).Range.InsertAfter "image00" & CStr(i)1` caused an error. Have you tried just using the line `docOpen.Shapes.SelectAll` and copying and pasting those?

Answer (score 1):

Word sometimes doesn't move to the page where the shape is located. This sometimes causes the shape to not select.

I found the ClipboardDataObject() had no formats when I got the error. GoForward() seems to get the shape to select.

In my code, wApp is an instance of Word.Application. This seemed to fix my C# code:

```
do
{
    wApp.GoForward();
    shape.Select();
    wApp.Selection.Copy();
} while (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats().Count() == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems at play here.

1. `docNew.Content.Paste` - `docNew.Content` is a `Range` that represents the entire content of the document. When you paste into this range you replace whatever it contained before. Instead paste into `docNew.Characters.First`
2. The second issue is that `Copy` and `Paste` invoke the clipboard, which is an OS function. As this function does not return anything to VBA to indicate that the process has completed your code just carries on executing. Using the clipboard repeatedly in code eventually builds timing issues as your code runs more quickly than the clipboard can respond. You may be able to deal with this by adding `DoEvents` after each copy and each paste to allow the OS to catch up.

So your code should be:

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes()
    Dim docOpen As Document
    Set docOpen = ActiveDocument
    Dim docNew As Document
    Set docNew = Documents.Add
    Dim i As Long
    
    docNew.SaveAs2 FileName:="Images.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    
        For i = docOpen.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            docOpen.InlineShapes(i).Range.InsertAfter "image00" & CStr(i)
            docOpen.InlineShapes(i).Range.Select
            Selection.Copy
            DoEvents
            docNew.Characters.First.Paste
            DoEvents
            docOpen.InlineShapes(i).Delete
        Next i
    docNew.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: the changes you suggest solve part of the problem: now several images get pasted into the new document, instead of only one. However, I am still getting error 4605 after a few iterations.
I assumed that the clipboard was getting too full and that that was causing the error, so I "empty" the clipboard with the command:
 docOpen.Range.Characters(1).Copy
(I know it is not really empty, but it is supposed to work well enough). However, that does not prevent the error from occurring. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I also tried to insert a 1-second delay (and then a 2-second delay) between the copying and the pasting, to allow more time for the DoEvents command (as suggested here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/558951/ms365-word-vba-selectionpaste-word-table-run-time.html). However, still no luck. I am still getting the error after a handful of iterations.

Comment: @DiegoSchiavon - it's running without errors for me.

Comment: Anyone figure out what this issue is? Im seeing this issue on some machines and not others when running a similar copy paste word table from a network location.

Answer (score -1):

Thats Due to Microsoft Windows' Clipboard Limit of 25 Items. for that you will have to use Win+V to go to clipboard history and choose clear all